# Enabling the Wireless Networking Feature in Hyper-V Server 2008 R2

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2008-r2, wifi, windows

I'm currently getting Hyper-V Server 2008 R2 working on my laptop.

Things are going reasonably well, but I can't get access to the wireless network adapter (from Hyper-V itself, not a guest VM).

I believe I need to enable the Wireless Network Service feature before it'll work.

Now, I've attached to the machine (over wired Ethernet) from another Windows Server 2008 R2 machine using Server Manager. But under Features, while I can see the one feature installed (Wow64 Support), I get no option to add a feature.

Anyone know why and what I can do to workaround it? If not, how do I add the Wireless Networking feature from the command line under Hyper-V itself (which is basically Server Core)?

Answer (score 1):

*edited out non-applicable info*

Yeah, I don't think it can do wireless, either.  Sorry.  :/

Comment: Unfortunately, this is Hyper-V Server 2008 R2, not Windows Server 2008 R2. You can't run Server Manager locally. If I run it remotely, I don't get the option of adding features (this is the same if I connect remotely to Win2k8R2, too!). 

What's worse, I'm not convinced that Hyper-V Server 2008 R2 actually has the Wireless LAN Service feature at all. :-(

Comment: Oh dang, reading comprehension is on the fritz today, apparently.